# How to bypass Cloudflare bot protection in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, cloudflare

I need to grab some information from a site just for education purpose, however i cannot send requests because of the protection. I get The typical Checking-your-browser page shows up first and then i'm being redirected repeatedly.
how i can bypass this protection in python selenium?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this problem a long time ago and I was able to solve it. Use the code below and enjoy :)

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r"webdriver\chromedriver.exe")
```

///////// EDIT ////////////////
this way now is not working !

Comment: Usually, it takes around 5 seconds for Cloudflare verification. You need to add a timer before you get page_source. Just add time.sleep(6) before driver.page_source

Comment: This does not work.

Answer (score 6):

Use [undetected_chromedriver pip package](https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/). This is very simple package for fake client.

```py
import undetected_chromedriver


def init_webdriver():
    driver = undetected_chromedriver.Chrome()

    driver.get(url)

    content = driver.page_content

    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

Also you can run it in background

```py
import undetected_chromedriver
from selenium import webdriver



def init_webdriver():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    driver = undetected_chromedriver.Chrome(options)

    driver.get(url)

    content = driver.page_content

    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

I tested it 28 Jun 2022. Works very well.

Comment: I got an error " RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

Answer (score 3):

A bit of a late response and no wonder why developers still face this issue repetitively. I am using Java v17 and Gradle v7.4.2.
My solution is related to the one explained above but the code is in Java.

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    // Bypass Cloudflare checks
    options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
    options.addArguments("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
```

Please refer to the Selenium ChromeOptions [documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeOptions.html) for further details.

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks @spicy-strike this was making me crazy. This piece of code saved my life.

Answer (score 2):

**As March 2022 :**

Hi, I had the same problem when using headless Selenium on a Docker Linux image.

I solved it by creating a virtualdisplay right before calling the webdriver:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 800))  
display.start()
```

**Don't forget** to install both pyvirtualdisplay and xvfb:
`pip install pyvirtualdisplay` and `sudo apt-get install xvfb`

And **you must remove the "headless" option** in ChromeDriver, here is the complete code I use :

```
    #Display in order to avoid CloudFare bot detection
    display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 800))  
    display.start()
  
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('start-maximized')
    options.add_argument('enable-automation')
    options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument('--disable-browser-side-navigation')
    options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
    # options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=options)
```

Since it was working nicely without headless on my local computer, I figured emulate a real display might do the work aswell.
I do not really understand why, but from what I've understood, CloudFare tries to execute javascript code in order to confirm you're not a bot. Having a emulated webpage display helps to do so.

Comment: `pyvirtualdisplay` doesn't export `Display` now. So the import line should be: `from pyvirtualdisplay.display import Display`. Also `visible` should be set to `False` or you'll get a type error.

Answer (score 1):

I am not providing a new kind of answer, but just sharing my up to date experience for others reference. I know the space is dynamic, but as of now 26/11/2023 the below seems to work for me. I am trying to scrape a popular property website because I am looking for a property to rent. If I open with Edge driver I get the common CloudFlare bot detection message and a check box captcha, which keeps looping:

*"site.com needs to review the security of your connection"*

And if I open with undetected_chromedriver it runs without being detected:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

my_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
my_options.add_argument( '--log-level=3' )
my_options.add_argument( '--no-sandbox' )
my_options.add_argument( '--disable-dev-shm-usage' )
my_options.add_argument( '--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled' )
my_options.add_argument( 'user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' )
my_options.add_argument( '--no-first-run' ) # this might be specific to undetected_chromedriver.v2 only
my_options.add_argument( '--no-service-autorun' ) # this might be specific to undetected_chromedriver.v2 only
my_options.add_argument( '--password-store=basic' ) # this might be specific to undetected_chromedriver.v2 only
#my_options.add_experimental_option( 'useAutomationExtension', False )
#my_options.add_experimental_option( 'excludeSwitches', ( 'enable-automation', ) )
my_options.add_argument( '--start-maximized' )
my_options.add_argument( '--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false' )
my_options.headless = False
my_options.page_load_strategy = 'normal'

my_driver = uc.Chrome( options = my_options, version_main = 109 )
my_driver.get( 'about:blank' )
my_driver.execute_script( "Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})" )
my_driver.get( ..............
```

Note: the two commented lines is not a type-o, it does work even when they are commented

Versioning: Windows 7x64, Python 3.8.10, Chrome x64 109.0.5414.120, undetected-chromedriver 3.5.4

Answer (score -2):

SOLUTION JULY 2021

just add user agent argument in chrome options and set user agent to any value

`ops = Options() ua='cat' ops.add_argument('--user-agent=%s' % ua) driver=uc.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=ops)`

Comment: Not working with this either. I'm using random useragent from fake_useragent but not working.