# How to pass cloudfire?

Tags: python, selenium

I have a code for making temp mail automatically but I have a problem.

This is code:

```py
    import time
    from selenium import webdriver

    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get("https://temp-mail.org/")
    time.sleep(10)
    browser.close()
```

The link opens correctly but I can't pass cloudflare.

[image: img]

Also, I see some errors on my console:

[image: img]

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding user agent argument in chrome options and set user agent to any value

```
ops = Options()
ua='me'
ops.add_argument('--user-agent=%s' % ua)  
driver=uc.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=ops)
```

Alternatively try using [undetected-chromedriver](https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/)

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://temp-mail.org/")
```

Comment: I tried but i got this error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax. How can i apply this to my code? can u help me pls

Comment: I installed and applied code but it doesn't work :( same issue...

Comment: Strange. Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64842858/selenium-app-redirect-to-cloudflare-page-when-hosted-on-heroku and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67341346/how-to-bypass-cloudflare-bot-protection-in-selenium these solutions looks like working

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64165726/selenium-stuck-on-checking-your-browser-before-accessing-url as well

Comment: Doesn't work :/ i will search other methods to bypass cloudfire...